# Returning enum name when returning records from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this Enum:

```
public enum TravelBy
    {
        AirPlain = 0,
        Ship=1,
        Train=2,
         Bicycle=3,
        Car = 4,
        Walk=5
    }
```

I want to return enum names when returning a record from the database.

For example, returning record for TravelBy `5` and I need to fill the property of model by `Walk`.

This is my model:

```
public class ListTravelRequest
{
    private readonly TravelBy travelby;
    private readonly SendTravelRequestStatus sendTravelRequestStatus;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public bool Owner { get; set; }
    public bool YouSend { get; set; }
    public string Resident { get; set; }
    public string RequestStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return sendTravelRequestStatus.ToDisplay();
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
    public string TravelBy
    {
        get
        {
            return travelby.GetEnumName();
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public string PeriodDate
    {
        get
        {
            return EndTravel.DiffDay(StartTravel).TotalDays.ToString();
        }
    }
    public DateTimeOffset StartTravel { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndTravel { get; set; }
    public decimal TravelCosts { get; set; }
}
```

But my problem is the following, for all records, it return first item in Enum `AirPlain` but when I check it in database it `5`.

Comment: Considering that the property `TravelBy` has no setter that does anything, its getter could not possibly return anything other than the default value, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i using this `public string Travelby
        {
            get
            {
                return travelby.GetEnumName();
            }
            set
            {
                travelby = TravelBy;
            }
        }` but it show me this error : `'TravelBy' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make `travelby` changeable (it's marked `readonly` now)
2. Add a setter, as follows: `set { travelby = (TravelBy)Enum.Parse(typeof(TravelBy), value); }`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your travelBy method by this please check the code.

```
public string TravelBy
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetName(typeof(TravelBy), here goes your value);
    }
    set
    {

    }
}
```